# Fullscreen Video/GIF Intro

Tags: plugins, media, front-end, videos, workflow

How would one go about placing a 3 second **Fullscreen Video**/GIF Intro **upon website start** **up** as a preloader.

I've tried coding it in but there's always something conflicting and limits the functionality of the website, and just doesn't feel, **proper**.

So what would be the best way to do it? **Plugin suggestions** are welcome as long as they are **free** :)

Thanks.

Comment: is it a video or a gif?  What theme are you using?  How should it appear?  You give very few details.

Comment: I have it in both formats, video and gif. Preferable to have it in video although i think it would be more optimized in gif. Also there is a problem if I do it in gif, I can’t define its stopping time which means at a slow network connection it’ll replay itself, which is something I don’t want. OceanSomething Theme. Should appear full screen instantly on website startup (just like preloader). What other details do you need?

Comment: You said "as a preloader".  Does that mean, when the page is loaded the video stops playing (even if its not finished) and the content displays?  Also, where is this video hosted?

Comment: No, the video fades away after it got to the end (3s). But the page loads while it’s playing. So priority to the video over page loading.

Comment: No sorry, haven’t had the time yet. I’ll let you know if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code uses [HTML5 Video](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/), with the muted & autoplay attributes set.  It takes the video, which I uploaded through the media gallery and displays it fullscreen.  I'm using a script that detects when the video is done playing, then it fades out and is removed from the DOM.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video muted autoplay id="fullscreen-bg-video">
        <source src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('fullscreen-bg-video').addEventListener('ended', detectEnd, false);

    function detectEnd(e) {
        jQuery('.fullscreen-bg').fadeOut(1000,function(){jQuery(this).remove();});
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .fullscreen-bg {
        background: #000;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    #fullscreen-bg-video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
        #fullscreen-bg-video {
            height: 300%;
            top: -100%;
        }
    }

    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
        #fullscreen-bg-video {
            width: 300%;
            left: -100%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

**Notes**

- As a test, I inserted all of the code into my header.php file but
  it's likely you will want to put this elsewhere.
- Upload a video in your media library and swap out the video src
- You can add a placeholder image for when the video is loading or to show on mobile by using the ["poster" attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp) on the video tag

Comment: Also the HTML should be best placed right after the opening body tag and the script right after it so it gets loaded first.

Comment: cheers mate (cheers mate)

Comment: RiddleMeThis - Your solution works very well. However, I have a question. Can I display an item only on a selected subpage? For example, based on the ID of this page?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/247883)